# Does closed set imply that the set is also bounded in Euclidean space?

Tags: real-analysis

In a Euclidean vector space, $\mathbb{R}^n$, does a set being closed imply that it is also bounded? In $\mathbb{R}$, if an interval is closed, doesn't that mean it must be bounded? I am not sure if this is also true in $\mathbb{R}^n$. My professor told me that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed set but clearly, it isn't bounded. Can anyone explain how this is true? Is this the only example I can find? I don't know why but it's hard to approve that a closed set can sometimes be unbounded.

Comment: A set is closed if it contains all its limit points. Clearly $\mathbb{R}^n$ trivially contains all its limit points.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a closed, unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Same for $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The complement of any open bounded set is a closed unbounded set.